# How to transactionally rollback consumed message in camel kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

I have a scenario where I need to consume a message from one Kafka topic and publish it to another Kafka topic.

```
    from("kafka:topic1?groupId=topic1&broker=broker1")
    .process(<business-logic>)
    .to("kafka:topic2?broker=broker2")
    .process(new Processor() {
          @Override
          public void process(Exchange exchange) {
            KafkaManualCommit kafkaManualCommit=exchange.getIn().getHeader(KafkaConstants.MANUAL_COMMIT,
                KafkaManualCommit.class);

            if(kafkaManualCommit!=null){
              kafkaManualCommit.commit();
              
            }
          }
        })
```

Suppose, if an exception occurred(e.g broker is not up) while publishing to the topic2. I need to roll back that consumed message. Again I need to re-process that(when the broker is up again).

Here topic1 & topic2 brokers are different.

Test scenario:

I purposely brought my broker2 down. Now I published 2 messages to the topic1.
After some time(around 10 mins). I brought mybroker2 up.

Now I'm able to send those 2 messages. In addition to that, It is getting consumed previous messages(whose offsets are committed already) and processes them again. I don't want that.

Kafka props:

```
      break-on-first-error: true
      allow-manual-commit : true
      auto-commit-enable: false
      auto-offset-reset: latest
```

Answer (score 0):

With kafka consumer api, by default committing offsets is done automatically (`enable.auto.commit=true`) and happened every period of time controlled by (`auto.commit.interval.ms=5000`)

So to reach your goal, you need to set 'enable.auto.commit=false' and you manage it from your application.

- [enable.auto.commit](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#enable-auto-commit)
- [auto.commit.interval.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#auto-commit-interval-ms)

Comment: @darkninja as per apache-camel docs it does the rolling back to the pervious offset, however it is not recommended as it might be a poison message, that got stuck forever and pile up a lag behind, however this doesn't apply for your specific case where the broker is down. https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/kafka-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_breakOnFirstError

Comment: @Sympl I've tried something and updated my question. could you please check what I'm missing there?

Comment: it is little bit confusing, however, something to know about the producer mode of operation, `send()` method is called async, so you can't know right after if the producer will be able to send the msg to the broker or not, as the producer use multiple configs to buffer and send the data in batches to the broker, I recommend you to have a look at the idempotent and transactional producer configs, however worth to mention that both features work within the same cluster not cross multiple clusters.
https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html